# Mercurial: how to change between branches without updating?

Tags: mercurial, repository

I creaated a branche, let's say **new_branch**.

I would like to change to the **default** branch **without** updating. This is, keeping the changes in my working copy (in **new_branch**) even if there were common files in **default**.

**Not** doing this:

```
hg update default  <-- don't want to update! Just to change the branch
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can clone the repo in another folder and start working on the default branch, but why do you want to change the branch without updating?

Comment: I would like to go to **default** and delete a commit. This commit has shared code in **new_branch**. I'm scared that if I deleted the code in default and, after that, go to **new_branch** the code will be deleted or changed from the state I have it now

Comment: When you say "delete a commit", what do you mean? `strip`, `backout` or something else? If `strip`, is the commit in question an ancestor of the tip of `new_branch`?

Comment: I have code in **default**. I did a branch **new_branch**,it uses code from default. Meanwhile, others could modify the code from the default -I'm supposed to do a merge at the end-. I want to delete -strip?- a commit from default without deleting it's "sons". Just delete the commit and continue with the actual code in my working copy.

Comment: The way you're talking about "deleting commits" and being "scared" changes in one branch will effect another shows you have a very limited understanding of how Mercurial works.  You should read the first few chapters of the mercurial book and firmly internalize the difference between the repository and the working directory.  @ChrisMorgan's very well meaning advice below is going to leave you hurting seriously until you understand what it actually does and how it doesn't apply to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Kani: Why don’t you make a testing-clone (or copy) of your repository, where you can try out how what you want to do on default affects new_branch? That will not affect the original repository, and you can experiment to your heart’s content. I make backups like this frequently whenever I’m about to do something that’s complicated or I’m not familiar with. I think being able to do this is a big advantage of Mercurial (or any DVCS) to SVN’s centralized model, where it’s hard to recover from mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

**Be careful. This answers your question *as asked*, but I'm not convinced it's what you *want*.**

`debugsetparents` will do it. But as noted, *be careful*.

> ~$ hg help debugsetparents
>   hg debugsetparents REV1 [REV2]
>
> manually set the parents of the current working directory
>
> > This is useful for writing repository conversion tools, but should be used
> >        with care.
> >
> > Returns 0 on success.
>
> options:
>
> > --mq  operate on patch repository
>
> use "hg -v help debugsetparents" to show global options

You want to set the parent to the last revision in the `default` branch.

You'll also need to use `hg debugrebuildstate` to fix the internal state (most obviously, its notion of which branch you're on).

```
hg debugsetparents default
hg debugrebuildstate
```